# Google Pub/Sub update Firestore sub collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to update a field in a subcollection every 2 minutes. I am changing the field "Status" to "Off" if the timestamp is older than 3 minutes old. I have this code that someone helped me with and It works with a collection but I dont know what collection path to use to access all documents that have this subcollection in them.

After 5 minutes I want the "Status" Field to be "Off" if the timestamp is more than 3 minutes old.

const snap = await db.collection("MX") works but only for 1 layer deep. Each document in userProfiles has a subCollection of MX.

I have tried wildcards and several different collection paths.

[image]

[image]

```
exports.updateIdle = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes').onRun(async () => {

const db = admin.firestore();
// this is what line I am trying to figure out
  const snap = await db.collection("userProfiles") 
    .where("Status", "=", "On")
    .where("Timestamp", "<", admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.now() - 3 * 60000))
    .get();


  await Promise.all(snap.docs.map(doc => doc.ref.update({Status: 'Off'})));

  console.log('this goes off every two minutes')
});
```

EDIT: 
userProfile ->  each doc -> 4 sub collections (MX, employees, settings, logs)

I have documents stored inside of MX. These documents will have a Status and a Timestamp.

I want this pub/sub to check all of the documents stored inside of the MX subcollection.

And if the timestamp is 3-5 minutes old, and Status = On. I want to change the Status to Off

So I am checking all MX subcollections. In this case there is 4 documents in userProfiles and there is a MX subcollection inside each document.

I appreciate any and all help. I hope I am explaining this well enough. Thanks.

Comment: Do you confirm that, in other words, you are looking for a solution to find documents of the `MX` collection that have an `MX` sub-collection

Comment: Yes. All docs inside userProfiles have an MX subcollection that I would like to access.

Comment: And you know that these docs do have an MX collection. Is your problem how to access the docs of this MX collection?

Comment: Also, is there a specific document in the `MX` subcollection of a `userProfile` that you want to update? Or you want to update all docs of this `userProfile/MX` subcollection?

Comment: Yes. I want this pub/sub to look at all of the docs in "MX", and if the "Timestamp" is more than 3 minutes old I would like to change "Status" to "Off"

Comment: I would like to update all docs in any MX subcollection that has an old timestamp.

If the timestamp is old I want all docs that exist inside ANY MX subcollection to change their "Status" field to Off

Comment: Pls have look at the proposed answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to "update all docs in any MX subcollection that has an old timestamp" the following should work, using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
exports.updateIdle = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes').onRun(async () => {

    const db = admin.firestore();

    const querySnapshot = await db.collection("userProfiles") 
        .where("Status", "=", "On")
        .where("Timestamp", "<", admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.now() - 3 * 60000))
        .get();
    
    const promises = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const docRef = doc.ref;
        promises.push(docRef.collection('MX').get());
    });
    
    const snapshotArrays = await Promise.all(promises);
    // snapshotArrays contains an array of arrays of QueryDocumentSnapshots

    const promises1 = [];
    
    snapshotArrays.forEach(snapArray => {
        snapArray.forEach(snap => {
            promises1.push(snap.ref.update({
                Status: "Off"
            }))
        })
    });
    
    return Promise.all(promises1);
    
});
```

---

Of course, I make the assumption that your initial query to find the `userProfile` docs with a "`timestamp` that is old" is correct.

---

### Update based on your comment

I understand that the filtering on "timestamp is 3-5 minutes old, and Status = On" is to be done at the level of the MX documents. The following should work then (we just move the `where` clauses to the `MX` collections). Note however that in this case we read all the `userProfile` documents (each read costing a standard document read).

```
exports.updateIdle = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes').onRun(async () => {

    const db = admin.firestore();

    const querySnapshot = await db.collection("userProfiles").get();

    const promises = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const docRef = doc.ref;
        promises.push(docRef.collection('MX').where("Status", "=", "On")
        .where("Timestamp", "<", admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.now() - 3 * 60000)).get());
    });

    const snapshotArrays = await Promise.all(promises);
    // snapshotArrays contains an array of arrays of QueryDocumentSnapshots

    const promises1 = [];

    snapshotArrays.forEach(snapArray => {
        snapArray.forEach(snap => {
            promises1.push(snap.ref.update({
                Status: "Off"
            }))
        })
    });

    return Promise.all(promises1);

});
```

---

If you still encounter errors, try without the where clauses as follows, and refien your where clauses in order to get the desired MX documents selection.

```
//....
const querySnapshot = await db.collection("userProfiles").get();

const promises = [];
querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    const docRef = doc.ref;
    promises.push(docRef.collection('MX').get());
});
//....
```

Comment: I get no errors, and a response of 'ok' but the Status Field never changes. The code I shared worked but only when the collection is one level deep. (one collection with one document)

Comment: Sorry but I have some difficulties to understand what you are exactly looking for. You said "All docs inside userProfiles have an MX subcollection that I would like to access". This is what the answer does IMHO. If it is not corresponding to your requirements, could you add some diagrams or very detailed textual explanations in your question?

Comment: Note that I have updated the answer: I forgot that this code is to be executed within a Cloud Function!!  So we should return the Promise returned by the last `Promise.all()`. See the update: `return Promise.all(promises1);`

Comment: I greatly appreciate your time. I have used the latest code and the same occurs. No error and responds with 'ok'. I added an EDIT to the post. One example of a document this should reach and change is ... /userProfiles/NBjjCvhBrkUEnvxvMbQouHTuwrI2/MX/Here .. This is a big help so of theres anything im not answering please let me know and I will try to re explain

Comment: You are welcome. Ok, I understand now that the query on `"Timestamp", "<", admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.now() - 3 * 60000)` shall be at the level of the `MX` collections, not at the level of the `userProfiles`one. Is that correct?

Comment: correct. The status and Timestamp fields are inside the MX documents. So Staus and Timestamp would exist inside MX/Here. "Here" being the document name

Comment: Ok! I got it now! See the update. As explained at the bottom of the answer: "If you still encounter errors, try without the where clauses, verify that the update works for all MX documents and then refine your where clauses in order to get the desired MX documents selection.

Comment: I can't thank you enough!! Works Perfect. Thanks again!!